# How do I stop this timer it self?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm using a timer to check a condition. I want to stop the timer once this if statement executed

```
  TimerFunction() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => {
      if(_status==PermissionStatus.granted){
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homepage()))        
      }
    });
  }
```

How to stop this timer itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cancel it. (It's passed in the callback.)

```
void startTimer() {
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
    if (_status == PermissionStatus.granted){
      t.cancel();
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Homepage()))
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new here and really appreciate your help :)